# Catching CTRL+V causes problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code successfully catches a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>/pasting in the input field "sURL" via jQuery. But how to directly obtain the pasted text afterwards?

My alert prompts an empty value. After a second paste, it prompts the first pasted text. But I'd like to handover the pasted text to a function just after the first <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sURL").bind('paste', function(e) {
        alert(document.WA.sURL.value);   <!-- returns empty value at 1st paste
    });
});
```

Comment: The first alert is empty because the alert triggers **before** the value has been pasted into the input field.. the second time you do it, the value is there. See [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/2095ooep/1/). How are you intending to pass on the value to another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways out :

**1)** Using clipboardData. This should work for IE also

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#sURL").bind('paste', function(e) {
            alert(e.clipboardData.getData('Text'));  
        });
    });
```

**2)** You can use a timer and paste it in a div with ID `paste`

```
$("#sURL").live('input paste',function(e){
        $('<textarea></textarea>').attr('id', 'paste').appendTo('#editMode');
        $("#paste").focus();
        setTimeout($(this).paste, 250);
});
```

*Try this out and let me know :)*

Comment: Thanks for contributing, Mohit.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the pasted text from clipboard data on the event `e`. The code below should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sURL").bind('paste', function(e) {
        alert(e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
    });
});
```

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7bLya9u/) to demonstrate too

Comment: Thank you for your response, Neil. It is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, possible covers all cases

```
$("#sURL").on('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain') || prompt('Paste something..');
    conosle.log(text);
    // myFunction(test);
});

function myFunction(str)
{
    // str contains the pasted string
    alert(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great!! The only thing I still have to get managed is how to pass over the Clipboard text to a function. I tried functionA(text); and functionA(text.toString); But it returns an error. "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'x.replace')" I was not able to figure out how to convert "text" to a variable which I can handover to a variable. Any idea?

Comment: Which function you want to pass the paste value to?

Comment: Just a regular function which shall process the clipboard string.

Comment: Thank you so much! Hopefully my last silly question: Is it possible to convert the variable "str" - see your example - to some sort of an object for operations such as str.match or str.split? I tried to figure it out on Stackoverflow (like convert to object), but I was not able to. :-(   These commands have worked before when using the function with something like myFunction("Just a test"). Any idea?

Comment: What exactly do you want your object to be like?

Comment: It should be a string with the possibility for operations like the ones I did before. (sCheck.split("\.html").length) - 1) ==1 && sCheck.match("\.html$") && sCheck.match("^http\:\/\/www\.test\.com\/")) Sorry, my Javascript is far from being professional.

Comment: Yes you can do this directly on the str, their wont be any issue :-)

Comment: You are my main of the day! I just had used a wrong command which wouldn't have worked with a regular string, neither. Now my solution is near perfect. Thank you, what a great community here!